# iOS Distribution: Migrating private key/certs to new machine

Tags: xcode, ios, osx-snow-leopard, keychain

I need to be able to submit updates to my application from a different machine than the one I used to submit the original.  I followed the instructions in the documentation, but, as usual, the documentation assumes everything works right the first time.

I tried exporting my developer profile from the old one to the new one, but when I submitted, App Loader said it was invalid signature.  So I tried to generate new certs (in order to do this in the Provisioning Portal, you have to revoke the existing ones).  It still didn't work.

Finally I had to go reclaim the old machine, which had not been wiped, and was able to submit my updates from it.

Aside from Apple documentation, which is less than complete, what steps do I need to take to port my developer certificates to a new machine so I can submit with the same distribution profile?

What do I do about the fact that I revoked the existing certs?  Can I regenerate ones with the original "private key" that still work for app updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this should be as simple as exporting and importing your developer identity in Xcode's organizer.  We will see if that works.