# Code Sign Error. Add new mac for developing

Tags: ios, xcode

I've done lots of search, tried lots of things, it just doesn't work.
I've been designing with a macbook, now I want to add another mac pro for developing. When I try to bun on my iPhone, it give me an error.

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

And in Organizer, under my device/Provisioning Profiles, the status is Valid Signing identity not found.

I want to use both mac for developing. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain that you can download the actual profile from here, but it's possible. Take a look around the Provisioning Portal: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

Comment: @XenElement I did it several times, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your profiles from your macbook and then import them on the new machine.  Take a look at [Copying keys and certificates to another one Mac for iPhone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404931/copying-keys-and-certificates-to-another-one-mac-for-iphone-development).

Comment: I'll try that. Hopefully it will work. Just curious, is there any other ways?

Comment: I understand you can go into the keychains yourself and transfer over individual items. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965554/code-sign-error-how-to-switch-an-xcode-project-over-to-another-mac.  I did an export and an import and it worked fine for me.  Fundamentally you have to migrate the keys as they cannot be recreated for security reasons (good reason to keep a backup of the export as well).

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I guess it was just being lazy to go back to my old macbook and do all the work. But spending a lot more time to solve the problem.